# Authenticate Google Sheets API Using Access Key in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access a Google Sheet stored in my Drive through the Google Sheets REST API.

This will just be a Python script without any user interaction. How can I authenticate my request using something like an access key or a service account?

I understand the concept of generating access keys or creating a service account in my Google Cloud console. But, I don't quite understand how the Sheet in my Drive can be associated with it.

I would like to know the steps I should follow in order to accomplish this. For instance, how can I send a request to this API endpoint?

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}
```

Note: I want to do this using the REST API. I do not want to use a Python API that has already been developed. So, I simply want to hit the above endpoint using maybe the `requests` package.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not permit API only access to Google (Workspace?) documents.

See [Authorizing Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

API keys authenticate programs.

OAuth is used to authenticate users and Google requires that users authenticate requests when access user data stored in Workspace documents.

[Domain-wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) enables the use of a Service Account to operate on behalf of users in situations such as this but it is only available for (paid) Workspace accounts.

I'm unsure how to refer to the free and paid (Workspace) versions.

Comment: If you have a paid subscription of Google Workspace, you can see the steps on how to do impersonation (Delegate domain-wide authority) with the services account [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).